# Array of object in JavaScript to View in ASP .NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Is it possible to get data from an array of objects in JavaScript, to .cshtml View.

Code for filling the newsObj[];

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Articles)
        {
           @:newsObj.push({
            @:Id:@item.Id,
            @:Title: "@item.Title",
            @:FeaturedImage: "@item.FeaturedImage",
            @:DateFormated: "@item.DateFormated",
            @:Summary: `@item.Summary.Trim()`,
            @:Category: "@foreach (var cat in @item.Category) {@(cat.Title+" ")} "});

          
        }
```

Code in View for displaying data from model called Articles:

```
<div class="novice-list">

                @foreach (var item in Model.Articles)
                {

                    <div class="novica-container">
                        <a href="@DataContext.Current.RouteUrlManager.GetModuleLink("article", null, "details", item.Id, item.Title)">
                            <div class="media">
                                @{
                                    string slika = string.Empty;
                                    if (item.Id > 166 || item.Id == 159)
                                    {
                                        slika = $"{WellKnownStrings.StorageBaseUrl}{WellKnownStrings.ArticleImageContainer}/{item.FeaturedImage}";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        slika = "https://kompasxnet.blob.core.windows.net/images/" + item.FeaturedImage;
                                    }
                                }
                                <div class="slika" style="background-image: url(' @slika ');">
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    @*<a href="#">content</a>*@
                                    <div class="meta">
                                        <span class="published">@item.DateFormated</span>
                                        <span class="category @foreach (var cat in @item.Category) { @(cat.Title+" ")}">
                                            @foreach (var cat in @item.Category)
                                            {
                                                <span class="cat @cat.Title">@cat.Title</span>
                                            }
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h2>@item.Title</h2>
                                    <p>@item.Summary</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    
                }
            </div>
```

The reason for this approach is the filtering, with the help of JS I filter the original array to another one. Now I have to display the filtered array back in view. Can that be done with **replaceWith()** or mybe with **innerHTML** ?

Comment: Why not try to call action to filter data,then refresh the model data,so that the page data will be refresh.If you want to use innerHTML,you need to  change the whole generated html code in `<div class="novice-list">`.

Comment: The newsObj[] is filterd in JS with the help of indexof(). So my filterd data are in newsObjFiltered[], then those values has to be passed to the view. 
What action do you mean ?

Comment: When you filter the Articles?I mean calling a controller action and pass Model to it,then change the Model.Articles,the action return the view with the filtered Model.Articles.

Comment: The model cannot be changed. Basicly the page currently gets  4 articles per page, I created a filter above those articles.  The problem was that the filter only filtered through displayed articles and not the whole collection. I cannot change the controller, thats why my solution is going in this direction. Im in my final step now, with passing filtered data from all articles to the view. Thats where Im stuck

Comment: What is your `"@DataContext.Current.RouteUrlManager.GetModuleLink("article", null, "details", item.Id, item.Title)"` and `$"{WellKnownStrings.StorageBaseUrl}{WellKnownStrings.ArticleImageContainer}/{item.FeaturedImage}";`.Can you share the data of it,so that I can try to share a demo with innerHTML.Or you can give me a sample data.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < newsObj.length; i++) {

                        if ((newsObj[i].Category).indexOf(selectedClass) != -1){

                            newsObjFiltered.push(newsObj[i]);
                        }


                    }  This is how I filter them into new array of objects

Comment: In that Line all I have to change is item.Id and item.Title into newsObjFiltered.Id and  newsObjFiltered.Title

Comment: Those are just classes to render data to get the correct url to a file(when user clicks on article) the second one is to get the featured picture of the article

Comment: I have to change all item.something to my newsObjFiltered.something, so that I can show the filtered data of all articles

Comment: Can you share the generated html code of `<a href="@DataContext.Current.RouteUrlManager.GetModuleLink("article", null, "details", item.Id, item.Title)">` and `<div class="slika" style="background-image: url(' @slika ');">`?Or I will just create a simple demo without the two elements.

Comment: In this fiddle is the generated html on the page :  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=86Vsou8kFS

Comment: Which one is `@item.Title` in "about-us/news/248/microsoft gold member".I need to know repalcing which one with the filtered Title.

Comment: Title = microsoft gold member ; Id= 248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change `<div class="novice-list">` to `<div class="novice-list" id="div1">`,and here is my js:

```
<script>
    var newsObj = [];
    $(function () {

        @foreach (var item in Model.Articles)
    {
       @:newsObj.push({
        @:Id:@item.Id,
        @:Title: "@item.Title",
        @:FeaturedImage: "@item.FeaturedImage",
        @:DateFormated: "@item.DateFormated",
        @:Summary: `@item.Summary.Trim()`,
        @:Category: "@foreach (var cat in @item.Category) {@(cat.Title+" ")} "});


    }
        console.log(newsObj);
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < newsObj.length-1; i++) {
            html += "<div class='novica-container'><a href ='/about-us/news/" + newsObj[i].Id + "/" + newsObj[i].Title + "'><div class='media'>";
            if (newsObj[i].Id > 166 || newsObj[i].Id == 159) {
                html += "<div class='slika' style='background-image: url(' https://fhr.blob.core.windows.net/article-image/" + newsObj[i].FeaturedImage+"');'>";
            } else
            {
                html += "<div class='slika' style='background-image: url(' https://kompasxnet.blob.core.windows.net/images/" + newsObj[i].FeaturedImage + "');'>";

            }
            html += "</div><div class='media-body'><div class='meta'><span class='published'>" + newsObj[i].DateFormated + "</span><span class='category " + newsObj[i].Category + "'>";
            for (var j = 0; j < newsObj[i].Category.trim().split(" ").length; j++)
            {
               
                html += "&nbsp;<span class='cat " + newsObj[i].Category.trim().split(" ")[j] + "'>" + newsObj[i].Category.trim().split(" ")[j]+"</span>";
            }
            html += "</span></div><h2>" + newsObj[i].Title + "</h2><p>" + newsObj[i].Summary + "</p></div></div></a></div>";

        }
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = html;
    })

</script>
```

result：
[image]

Comment: So the catch is that you give all the values to variable html and then with the help of inner html inserted that in page. What is the point of the new aded ID =div1. Couldn't I just use the class for innerHtml. I will try to implement it now, and will let you know how it works. Thank you for all the help, you da real mvp 

Comment: Hello,if my answer is helpful,can you mark it as answer?Thank you.

Comment: I did :) Thanks again . Can you upvote my question, im trying to get rid of my ban. I deleted one post and now my actions here are restricted..